# uuidgen has consistent 13th digit and it's 4

Tags: randomness

I ran `uuidgen` 10k times and noticed that the 13th digit is always 4.
Why is that?

[image: UUIDS from uuidgen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a full explanation in the Wikipedia article on [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

UUID's come in different versions. The 4 you highlighted indicates version 4 was used where the UUID is created by generating a random number. Other versions use for example the date-time and MAC address of your computer.

When you look further at the first character of the next block you will see it is not very random either: it shows only the characters 8, 9, A and B . This is because the two most significant bits are `01` for the variant of this UUID version.

Answer (score 2):

It's the version number of the UUID type /algorithm. This is a version 4 UUID which means that it's made using an upstream OS random number generator, rather than made from a namespace or network card MAC.  It also means that it only has 122 bits of entropy, rather than the 128 you thought it did. That's still 5 undecillion values, but less than you thought.

See the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for more details, especially the version types and other restrictions on the format.